# Transaction Log Restore: System objects could not be updated in database because it is read-only

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I want to set up a secundary copy of a large ERP production database, which would be used as read-only database for reporting purposes. Regular backup jobs on production DB are already configured: a full backup every night and regular transaction log backups every 15 minutes.

I'm restoring a full backup and then applying transaction log backups (with STANDBY option). The restore of transaction log is successful, but I always get a message at the end that the system objects could not be updated:

```
Processed 7 pages for database ..., file ... on file 1. 
System objects could not be updated in database ... because it is read-only. 
System objects could not be updated in database ... because it is read-only. 
RESTORE LOG successfully processed 7 pages in 0.029 seconds (1.633 MB/sec).
```

It seems that the restore is successful. However, the warning (error?) regarding the system objects is confusing. Is it something I should pay attention to? What is the reason for the error? I couldn't find any similar problem on the Microsoft support forums...

Update: SQL Server version is 11.0.7469.6 (2012 with all service packs and hotfixes)

Comment: Do both the servers have the same version (up to CU)?

Comment: not to the CU. production server (where backups are made) has 11.0.5676, new server (where restores are made) has 11.0.7469.6.

Comment: My guess was on contrary, in case when primary is more up to date, it was trying to upgrade also system objects, at least the version

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind I'll suggest you a workaround(There might be a solution)

step 1. Restore the full backup to a new database and ensure the backup is successful(by accessing some objects).

step 2. restore the transaction backups 2(some count let say 3 or some number) at a time and make db to recovery state then query the same objects which were done at step 1.

step 3. repeat the process until all the backups were restored successfully.

Also check the following [link](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1706107-3411-1.aspx), might work.